# Proper way to specify an angle

Tags: notation, angle

This is less a math question and more a semantic one. Suppose A and B are two arbitrary axes and I'm interested in an angle of a vector emanating from the origin. If I refer to vector's "angle between A and B" does this grammatically mean that the A-axis points right, the B-axis points up and the angle is traced counterclockwise from A to B? Thus, if I referred to the vector's "angle between B and A" then the axes would be flipped: B would be what is traditionally the x-axis and A would be the traditional y-axis.

I'm afraid I might be off here...as in this phrase structure could be informal and may have no standard meaning. If that's the case, how should I distinguish between these two angles? (I'm assuming the axis names are fixed and can't just be relabeled however is most convenient.)

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking. Typically, when similar question is asked, we are usually asked something along the lines of "what is the angle between vector ${v}$ and the A axis?" or "what is the angle between vector ${v}$ and the B axis?" or, more generally, "what is the angle between vectors $v$ and $u$ ?"

Comment: Let me give some background. In the problem that motivated this, I have 3 dimensions (x, y and z). Thus two angles and a radius are associated with every point. I'd have no issues if I could just report the standard polar angle (between z and y) and azimuthal angle (between x and y). Unfortunately, due to the nature of the problem, it is more intuitive for some to think of the angle between y and x (so to speak) rather than the azimuthal angle. I simply wanted to make this distinction clear when I report this angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, an **angle** is always measured as increasing in a counter-clockwise manner, and decreasing in a clockwise manner. For a fractional circular measure which increases clockwise and decreases counter-clockwise, the correct terminology is a **bearing**. So if you were to report a fractional circular measure of direction of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ which increases from the $y$-axis in a clockwise manner, you could say, "The vector $\mathbf{v}$ has a bearing of $57.3^\circ $ [to the $y$-axis]," where [to the $y$-axis] can be omitted if there is a convention that is made obvious. I have never seen the term bearing used mathematics, since we can easily give a negative angle. However, it is frequently used in real world navigation, where the convention for the $y$-axis is North.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working more within a physics rather than a strictly math context. Come to think of it, I've seen references to the bearing when dealing with this problem. Now I know why! This seems to be a solid grammatical alternative.